# How do i make my chat message private?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, ejs

Now my chat is working but it works like a group message as a third party will be able to see the messages. I want to make it private between two users so that when a third user log in, they will not be able to see the other users talking.

```
var io = socket(server);


io.on("connection", function(socket){
    console.log("made socket connection", socket.id);

    socket.on("chat", function(data){
        var messages = {
            session: data.session,
            message: data.message,
            sender: data.handle,
        };
        MsgModel.create(messages);
        io.sockets.emit("chat", data);
    });

    socket.on("typing", function(data){
        socket.broadcast.emit("typing", data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Emit a `join` event from client whenever a new client joins with their `userid` as data. Then on server side, you can use this `join` event to add user to a room with its `userid`.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on("join", function(data){
      socket.join(data.userId)
    })
  })
```

Now you have rooms with every `userid` and if you want to send some specific user something, you can emit to that room,

```
io.to(userid).emit(data)
```